# How does Django's Rest Framework's ModelSerializer overriding works?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am following case I can't figure out how the following code which uses rest_framework is working. I looked in the documentation but was not able to find much help there.
( This code comes from a django tutorial but no information was given there)

Here is the model:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self",blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=140,validators=[validate_content])
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And the serializers:

```
class TweetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True) #write_only
    date_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    timesince = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    parent = ParentTweetModelSerializer(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Tweet
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'content',
            'timestamp',
            'date_display',
            'timesince',
            'parent'
        ] 
// other lines of code
class ParentTweetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDisplaySerializer(read_only=True) #write_only
    date_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    timesince = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

So parent is a field in my original Tweet model but when I use a Serializer to override or replace the field "parent",how can the ParentTweetModelSerializer determine which parent tweet is related TweetModelSerializer's tweet with it without us passing any data to it ( as we didnt passed anything in ParentTweetModelSerializer() ?

I was unable to find anything related with it in the rest_framework's documentation.

Comment: You still need to pass in your serialized ParentTweet object. If you're using a normal ModelSerializer, and you have a ForeignKey field, you simply need to pass in the primary key of the object. But with nested serializers in your case, you can't update the nested serializer data at the same time as you update your TweetModelSerializer and need to do these two things separately. I found this [DjangoCon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-9WniUBt0fo) useful.